# How do I convert mcrypt PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, mcrypt

How do I convert this to Python? What I'm confused is the random vi.

PHP

```
public function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
    {
    $sValue =  $this->pkcs5_pad($sValue, mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'ecb'));
      return rtrim(
            base64_encode(
                mcrypt_encrypt(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                    $sSecretKey, $sValue,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                    mcrypt_create_iv(
                        mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                        ),
                        MCRYPT_RAND)
                    )
                ), "\0"
            );
    }
```

UPDATE:

this works exactly how it should!

Python

```
secret_key = 'he21jodkio1289ij'
value = 'hello'

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
PADDING = '\0'
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Well… of course that doesn't work. Your Python code is using a completely different cipher!

Comment: And different modes and different padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The PHP code is using RIJNDAEL_128 which is AES, the Python code is using DES, they both need to use the same encryption algorithm in order to interoperate.
- The PHP code is using ECB mode but Python code is using CBC mode, they both need to use the same mode in order to interoperate.
- The PHP code mcrypt (which should not be used) uses non-standard null padding, the Python code is using PKCS#5 padding which is standard, they both need to use the same padding in order to interoperate.

Note1: ECB  mode does not use an IV. If an IV is provided for ECB mode it is ignored.

Note 2: Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.